# How to write a conditional operator (?:) without using else

Tags: c

While programming in C, I am using conditional operator (?:). But I don't want to use else part.

```
if(x!=1){printf("Hello");}
```

How can I write using conditional operator?

Comment: @Frankie_C that won't even compile.

Comment: Don't attempt to use the conditional operator for this - it's not intended for control flow.

Comment: The difference between conditional operators and if statements are similar to flathead and Phillips screwdrivers - you can use a flathead in the place of a Phillips sometimes, but it isn't the best fit for the job. One of the main purposes of a conditional statement is to change the value you assign to a variable depending on a condition. It isn't intended as a drop-in replacement for an if-statement *per se*.

Comment: Doen't work . throws a syntax error

Comment: Sorry I forgot that the ternary operator `?` doesn't work outside an expression. This x!=1 ? printf("Hello"); : ;. can't work. On the other hand it is of no use without the else part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While they appear similar in function, conditional operators are not the same as conditional statements (IF statements).

The main purpose of a conditional operator is to change what value is assigned to a variable, depending on a condition.

Given the following (terrible) example...

```
if(raining==true)
{
    take="umbrella";
}
else if(raining==false)
{
    take="sunglasses";
}
```

That can be rewritten simply as:

```
take=(raining ? "umbrella" : "sunglasses");
```

That's the main purpose of a conditional operator. But, as Oliver Charlesworth said in the comments, it is not intended for control flow.

Thus, as a general rule, if you find yourself in a place where you want a conditional operator without the else, **you're using conditional operators incorrectly.**

Comment: Secondary purpose of conditional operator if quickly making C/C++/Java program unreadable.

Comment: @jdarthenay, ha ha, when used improperly, it certainly does!! I do notice that, when used *wisely*, it actually increases readability. I rather like them myself, for certain situations like the one I posted in my answer. Outside of stuff like that, or when overused, it's a veritable smoke-screen.

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator `?:` requires an expression if the condition isn't met, you could always place a "dummy" value there such as the value `0` like in the following example:

`x != 1 ? printf("Hello") : 0;`

An "if" statement would probably be the better way to go in cases like these.

Comment: I was looking for something where it doesn't return anything .

Comment: This is a perfectly valid statement. A statement can be valid even if it does not assign the result. For example the statement `x;` is an expression whose value is not assigned to anything, but compiles. In the same way, the expression in this answer either has the value returned by `printf` or `0`, but it is not assigned to anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is a different operator `&&` and it allows you to omit the else part:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int x = 1;

    x != 1 && printf ("Hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Try running the program, then change `x` to `2` and run again.

Comment: This is even more obtuse.  Please don't do this.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Don't do this because the earth will shake, in two will break?